# Iterating through a specified registry subkey

Tags: python-3.x, iteration, registry

I'm developing a Windows Registry editor in Python 3.

At the moment my function to query the SOFTWARE key in the CURRENT_USER hive is outputting what I want, I am looking to have a user specify which subkey they want to query for example the Python subkey, and iterate through that but cannot work this out.

My code so far:

```
def query_registry():
    registry_path = winreg.ConnectRegistry(None, winreg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER)
    registry_key = winreg.OpenKey(registry_path, r"SOFTWARE\\", 0, winreg.KEY_READ)

    for i in range(200):
        try:
            subkey_name = winreg.EnumKey(registry_key, i)
            print(i, "-", subkey_name)
        except:
            print("Number of Directories --> %s" %i + "\n")
            break
```

The output:

[image]

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Make the `query_registry()` function more universal to call itself recursively e.g. as follows (sorry for too little *pythonish* code):

```
def query_registry( sargpath, sargxst):
    print(sargpath)
    iargxst = int( sargxst)
    registry_path = winreg.ConnectRegistry(None, winreg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER)
    registry_key  = winreg.OpenKey(registry_path, sargpath, 0, winreg.KEY_READ)
    info_key      = winreg.QueryInfoKey(registry_key)
    if ( iargxst < 0 ):
        for i in range(info_key[0]):
            subkey_name = winreg.EnumKey(registry_key, i)
            print(i, "-", subkey_name)
        print("Number of Directories --> %s\n" %(info_key[0]))
        ###
        if ( info_key[0] > 0 ):
            x = input('Enter subkey number (-1 to end): ')
            if ( int(x) in range(info_key[0]) ):
                subkey_name = winreg.EnumKey(registry_key, int(x))
                query_registry( sargpath + '\\' + subkey_name , -1 )
            else:
                exit()
    else:
        subkey_name = winreg.EnumKey(registry_key, iargxst)
        query_registry( sargpath + '\\' + subkey_name ,-1 )

### main ###
import sys
import winreg
query_registry(sys.argv[1],sys.argv[2])
```

Result example:

```
==> D:\bat\SO\53808855.py "software" 19
software
software\Google
0 - Chrome
1 - Common
2 - Software Removal Tool
3 - Update
Number of Directories --> 4

Enter subkey number (-1 to end): 0
software\Google\Chrome
0 - BLBeacon
1 - BLFinchList
2 - BrowserCrashDumpAttempts
3 - BrowserExitCodes
4 - Extensions
5 - NativeMessagingHosts
6 - PreferenceMACs
7 - StabilityMetrics
8 - ThirdParty
Number of Directories --> 9

Enter subkey number (-1 to end): 6
software\Google\Chrome\PreferenceMACs
0 - Default
1 - Guest Profile
2 - Profile 2
3 - Profile 3
4 - System Profile
Number of Directories --> 5

Enter subkey number (-1 to end): -1

==>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer Josef, I just wanted to ask, sargpath, sargxst, iargxst these variable names are confusing to me. What exactly are they representing? I see one is for a path and another for argument?, I just wanted to clarify this for context.

Comment: I am getting invalid syntax errors because of the line 26, query_registry( sargpath + '\\' + subkey_name , -1 ), im guessing because we are calling the function within itself we have to use the self?

Comment: @Atreyu about naming e.g. `sargpath` you can read as **s**tring**arg**ument**path**, `sargxst` as **s**tring**arg**ument**xst** where **xst** is my faulty abbreviation for a subkey _sequence number_ (should be rather **xth**?). As you can see I don't get any syntax error using `Python 3.5.1 (v3.5.1:37a07cee5969, Dec  6 2015, 01:54:25) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32`.